# Why does Rust's example guessing game allow a match statement with varying return types?

Tags: rust, match, continue

Looking at the guessing game example from [the intro book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html), specifically the part where you use a `match` statement to perform error-handling:

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => continue,
};
```

Why doesn't it complain that the different arms of the `match` statement have different return types? One returns a `u32`, the other executes a `continue` statement and doesn't return anything. I thought either all arms of a `match` statement must execute code, or all arms must return something of the same type as one another.

Comment: Ok is for success and carries the value into the parameters which is then returned to the variable well as
Err carries takes the Errors being handled and executes the exceptions provided thus continues.

Comment: The book expains it [later](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#the-never-type-that-never-returns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`continue` has type [`!` (AKA "never")](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html), [which can coerce into any other type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types), since no values of it can exist.